# How to empty a buffer before it gets to0 large

Tags: buffers

I'm browsing with `erc` to some channels which are mainly used by bot request. Therefore the buffer size will scale up very fast. Since It's a read-only buffer I cannot empty it by hand. Is there a way to tell Emacs to empty a buffer if it reaches a specific size?

Comment: Have a look at my configuration for clearing eshell. Not sure how to clear if it reaches a specific size but it might be a start [link](https://github.com/Xparx/emacs-init/blob/master/emacs-init.org#make-c-l-clear-m-x-eshell-buffers)

Comment: In what way is the buffer read only? Perhaps you can simply turn the read only flag off by using C-x C-q?

Comment: Doesn't work - already tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found `erc-truncate-mode`. You have to change this variable 
`erc-max-buffer-size`

> Maximum size in chars of each ERC buffer. Used only
>   when auto-truncation is enabled.